# Unable to get the desired web link at the time of web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to do web scraping using BeautifulSoup4 but it doesn't work to get the links I want. How can I get the link I want when doing web scrapping?

```
url_web = {
    "cnn" : "https://www.cnnindonesia.com/search/?query=citayam&page=",
    "detik" : "https://www.detik.com/search/searchall?query=citayam&siteid=2",
    "kompas" : "https://search.kompas.com/search/?q=citayam&submit=Submit"
}

list_cnn = []

for i in range(1, 33):
  URL = url_web['cnn']+str(i)
  print(i, '/',1, ' - ', URL)
  page = requests.get(URL)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  print(soup)
  results = soup.find("div", class_="media_rows")
  for result in results.find_all("a"):
    print(result)
    href_elem = result.get('href')
    list_cnn.append(href_elem)
  print(list_cnn)

root_path = 'gdrive/My Drive/analisa_cfw/'
with open(root_path+'list_cnn.json', "w", encoding='utf8') as outfile:
  json.dump(list_cnn, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
print("Tokenized_sent json saved!")
```

Comment: What do you want and what do you get?

Comment: what means `doesn't work`? If you get error message then show it in question (not in comment). If you get wrong result then show it in question and show expected result. We can't read in your mind and you have to describe all details in question.

Comment: you try to get links from 3 diferrent urls - but pages may have different structures and the same code may not work for all pages. Every pages may have unique structure and every page may need unique code to get links.

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this section of your code here:

```
results = soup.find("div", class_="media_rows")
for result in results.find_all("a"):
    print(result)
    href_elem = result.get('href')
    list_cnn.append(href_elem)
```

with this here:

```
results = soup.find_all("article")
for result in results:
    try:
        a = result.find('a')
        href_elem = a.get('href')
        print(href_elem)
        list_cnn.append(href_elem)
    except:
        pass
```

complete code here:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_web = {
    "cnn": "https://www.cnnindonesia.com/search/?query=citayam&page=",
    "detik": "https://www.detik.com/search/searchall?query=citayam&siteid=2",
    "kompas": "https://search.kompas.com/search/?q=citayam&submit=Submit"
}

list_cnn = []
for i in range(1, 33):
    URL = url_web['cnn']+str(i)
    print(i, '/', 1, ' - ', URL)
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all("article")
    for result in results:
        try:
            a = result.find('a')
            href_elem = a.get('href')
            print(href_elem)
            list_cnn.append(href_elem)
        except:
            pass

root_path = 'gdrive/My Drive/analisa_cfw/'
with open(root_path+'list_cnn.json', "w", encoding='utf8') as outfile:

    json.dump(list_cnn, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
print("Tokenized_sent json saved!")
```

Comment: Just a note - `except:pass` is not good programming. Internet is full of discussions about this.